# Importing Settings.initializeSDK from react-native-fbsdk-next fails with TypeError: null is not an object

Tags: react-native, scala.js

I'm a react/scala.js noob and am trying to create a slinky/react-native app that supports facebook login.

I'm trying to initialise the facebook SDK by doing the following

```
object FbSdkSettings {
  @js.native
  @JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", "Settings.initializeSDK")
  def initializeSDK(): Nothing = js.native
}
```

However when the button that calls that code is clicked on, it throws this error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Settings.initializeSDK')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
```

Also tried the following with the same result

```
@js.native
@JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", "Settings")
object FbSdkSettings extends js.Object {

  def initializeSDK(): Nothing = js.native
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, I did not have the android/ios boilerplate needed to make the FB lib calls work.
The approach above was to take a sample expo + slinky + scala.js app and introduce FB login to it. That seems to not work easily because react-native-fbsdk-next depends on native code and I was missing that boilerplate.
I changed the approach to taking a working react-native app(with the necessary boilerplate) and introduce slinky + scala.js to it.
The same code as above seems to work in that case.
Not a perfect answer but then I am a noob to app development.